# "install xlrd" satisfied and at the same time not

Tags: python-3.x

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
$ pip3 install xlrd
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.1)

I have installed xlrd but again asking me to install it. I am running in an empty circle here!
Using Python3, Mac terminal.

Comment: Hi Maher, any updates. I am too running into same issue on Python3, Mac machine using Pycharm IDE.

Comment: Go into the settings (CTRL + ALT + s) and search for project interpreter you will see all of the installed packages. Click the + button at the top right and search for xlrd, then click install package at the bottom left.

Comment: Try the above one. It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Go into the settings (CTRL + ALT + s) and search for project interpreter you will see all of the installed packages. Click the + button at the top right and search for xlrd, then click install package at the bottom left.